# Can I have a single Meteor sign-in across subdomains?

Tags: meteor, subdomain, user-accounts

I have just deployed a site built using [Meteor 0.7.2](https://www.meteor.com/), which is served at both example.com and www.example.com.

If a user signs in on one (e.g. www.example.com), they are not signed in on the other (e.g. example.com).

Is there a way to have a single sign-in across the two subdomains? Or should I simply redirect the user away from one of them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor uses `localStorage` (instead of session cookies) for storing authentication information. This `localStorage` is not accessible to any other site, including super-domains. Hence, redirecting, IMO, is the best option here.

Comment: Core Meteor developer Emily Stark recent blogged about using localStorage vs cookies and how this restriction on access is a nice security feature:  https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/03/14/session-cookies

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by rolling your own API by extending accounts Oauth
Check out this article:
http://meteorhacks.com/extending-meteor-accounts.html